# How to click on button at a time in Angular

Tags: angular

The goal is to create an accordion that opens and close when the title is clicked. So far anytime I click any button on the page, they all open or close, How do I specify my code to only open the one that was clicked?

```html
<div class="accordian">
    <div class="accordian-item">
        <h2 class="accordian-title" (click)="toogleTag()" [ngClass]="isHidden ? 'active-header' : 'accordian-title'">
            This is a Test Question 1</h2>
        <p class="accordian-answer" [hidden]="isHidden">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Pariatur
            sit consequatur
            tempore iusto magnam quam optio provident minus aut aliquid, suscipit nam quas hic fugiat praesentium
            assumenda recusandae reprehenderit sint est repudiandae, odit unde dignissimos nostrum. Autem fugiat
            suscipit officiis doloremque, aperiam delectus nulla dolorem optio quisquam sequi perspiciatis! Officiis
            assumenda beatae eligendi laudantium labore ut, provident ipsum tenetur ea quas illo dolorem temporibus
            magni maiores quia aperiam et rerum deserunt eaque distinctio esse molestias quae aspernatur. Ab commodi
            doloribus ratione excepturi quaerat iste ipsum fugit vel minima quibusdam facere nisi natus, cupiditate
            adipisci fuga nesciunt cumque dolorem corporis explicabo.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="accordian-item">
        <h2 class="accordian-title" (click)="toogleTag()" [ngClass]="isHidden ? 'active-header' : 'accordian-title'">
            This is a Test Question 2</h2>
        <p class="accordian-answer" [hidden]="isHidden">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Pariatur
            sit consequatur
            tempore iusto magnam quam optio provident minus aut aliquid, suscipit nam quas hic fugiat praesentium
            assumenda recusandae reprehenderit sint est repudiandae, odit unde dignissimos nostrum. Autem fugiat
            suscipit officiis doloremque, aperiam delectus nulla dolorem optio quisquam sequi perspiciatis! Officiis
            assumenda beatae eligendi laudantium labore ut, provident ipsum tenetur ea quas illo dolorem temporibus
            magni maiores quia aperiam et rerum deserunt eaque distinctio esse molestias quae aspernatur. Ab commodi
            doloribus ratione excepturi quaerat iste ipsum fugit vel minima quibusdam facere nisi natus, cupiditate
            adipisci fuga nesciunt cumque dolorem corporis explicabo.</p>

    </div>
```

In my TS file I have:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buttons',
  templateUrl: './buttons.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./buttons.component.scss']
})
export class ButtonsComponent implements OnInit {
 isHidden:boolean = true
 accordianTitle:any = document.getElementsByClassName("accordian-title")
 
 
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
  toogleTag(){
      this.isHidden = !this.isHidden       
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when material expansion panel does just that? 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3w31n8?file=src/app/expansion-overview-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You are using `isHidden`  for both accordians. When you make it true or false, it will reflect on both.
Instead try this: https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview